# How can i run a python script from visual studio using module based on Cpython?

Tags: python, c#, cpython

I write a Process in c# to run a python script:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        private void run_cmd(string loadifc)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = "D:/Annaconda/python.exe";
            start.Arguments = String.Format("{0}",loadifc);
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.run_cmd("D:/DOC/BA/IFCfileEnd/RunPythonfromC/TransitionNachschlagen.py"); 
        }
    }
}
```

It seems ok to open and run the python script. But in python script I need to import a module named Ifcopenshell. TThis Module cant open with python 3.8, and here is Errormessage:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\ifcopenshell\ifcopenshell_wrapper.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1101, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ifcopenshell_wrapper: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\ifcopenshell\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from . import ifcopenshell_wrapper
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\ifcopenshell\ifcopenshell_wrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    _ifcopenshell_wrapper = swig_import_helper()
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\ifcopenshell\ifcopenshell_wrapper.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_ifcopenshell_wrapper')
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ifcopenshell_wrapper'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/DOC/BA/IFCfileEnd/RunPythonfromC/TransitionNachschlagen.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ifcopenshell
  File "D:\Annaconda\lib\site-packages\ifcopenshell\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    raise ImportError("IfcOpenShell not built for '%s'" % python_distribution)
ImportError: IfcOpenShell not built for 'windows\64bit\python3.8'
```

But, Python 3.8 is truthly fit for ifcopenshell. The developer of Ifcopenshell says it is because Ifcopenshell base on cpython, but .Net Framework base on ironpython. And he advice me to write a Json to solve it. But I really want to run this script in Visual studio with a WPF button. So, how can I make it?

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? They are two very different products.

Comment: @KlausD. Maybe he can get it to work with `ed`

Comment: @KlausD. Visual Studio.

Comment: @rioV8 what u mean ed?

Comment: `ed` is the Unix line editor, your question has nothing to do with the editor you use to modify the file

Comment: @riov8 ok, u mean 'ed' is not the solution? Maybe I should write a Json to save result from python IDLE, but at least can I start to run a python script with a button in wpf application. I mean, start a another process with all resources in the outside of  visualsutido, nomore try to bring all the resources into visual studio to run a process.

Comment: why is the type of build of any executable of influence in starting a new process and running an executable build in some way

Comment: @rioV8 because my mission is to add some new function into a WPF applicaiton, and I need to use some function of it for later. So it should starts from Visual Studio, and ends back to Visual Studio.